# PayPal Merchant API - Getting Products Information

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

New to using PayPal, and had a general question regarding what it can provide.

The need is to enable someone with a merchant account on PayPal to login to a website (meaning the api should probably be in javascript) and then get from the API information about the products the merchant supplies.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Sincerely,

-Lior

Answer (score 0):

PayPal doesn't have any way to store actual inventory data.  If you process orders with item details included then you pull those details using GetTransactionDetails.

If you're using the Button Manager API you could create individual buttons for different products with inventory tracking enabled on those and then you could potentially pull "inventory" data by pulling the buttons.  I wouldn't recommend that, though.

Really, the best thing to do would be to manage your inventory in your own system of some sort.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, friend. Making one thing clear though - 

There's no need for inventory information - only product information. That is, what's necessary is to get the information regarding the merchant's catalog (we don't care about if something is in stock or not). Is that possible? Does the merchant account allow for creation of products and their information can be accessible via the API? 

Thanks again!

Comment: No, PayPal doesn't have a way to create "products" in their system.  You will need your own system to manage Products and then you can send product details in an order request to PayPal.  Again, the Button Manager API would be a potential work-around type of a solution, but just having your own Products system would be better.  There are so many options for that already it's really not something PayPal deals with.  They handle payments.

Comment: Great, got it - thanks! One final thing, does PayPal at least allow me to configure the account to which a "Buy Now" button will transfer funds? For example, does this Button Manager API allows for that?